# makefile linking error -lSDL (linux)

Tags: gcc, compilation, makefile, linker

I recently tried to make a makefile and it works fine on my laptop. I was making a game in c++ and shared my code on github. One of my friends cloned
the repo and informed me that he ran into some errors. Coming to errors I must inform you that my project uses QuickCG which is based on SDL, so naturally one needs to have SDL installed. My friend did not have that initially but later downloaded it using `sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2-dev`. After downloading, the 'header include' error was removed but still there is linking error I suppose.
Here is my makefile

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -c -O3
CLINK_FLAGS = -lSDL
all : game
game : main.o quickcg.o
    $(CC) main.o quickcg.o -o game $(CLINK_FLAGS)
main.o : main.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.cpp
quickcg.o : quickcg.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) quickcg.cpp
clean :
    rm *.o game
```

My Game folder contains only 2 cpp files which are main.cpp and quickcg.cpp. It also contains 1 header file quickcg.h

Now to come to the exact error statement after executing make

```
g++ -c -O3 main.cpp
g++ -c -O3 quickcg.cpp
g++ main.o quickcg.o -o game -lSDL
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lSDL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [game] Error 1
```

Please note that this worked completely fine on my laptop.
Also please note that the following command worked like a charm even on his laptop

```
g++ *.cpp -lSDL -O3
```

So clearly there seems to be a fault with makefile.
Forgive me if I have done anything stupid because I am new to makefiles but I am not able to find any errors here. Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the output of `g++ *.cpp -lSDL -O3 -v` on your friend's machine?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/WdmFF2Fv
Here is the output. Any ideas?

Comment: Now add the option when using the makefile, you need to have a look at the very last lines that start with `-L`, if it can't find the library then these paths should be different.

Answer (score 0):

You may try

```
CLINK_FLAGS = `sdl-config --libs`
```

if you don't know the path for -L.